# java.io.IOException at RabbitMq connectionFactory initialization

Tags: java, exception, rabbitmq, ioexception

When I try to make a .newConnection() to a rabbitMQ server I get the follwing error:

> java.io.IOException
>       at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.wrap(AMQChannel.java:126)
>         at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.wrap(AMQChannel.java:122)
>         at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection.start(AMQConnection.java:373)
>         at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.recovery.RecoveryAwareAMQConnectionFactory.newConnection(RecoveryAwareAMQConnectionFactory.java:64)
>         at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.recovery.AutorecoveringConnection.init(AutorecoveringConnection.java:134)
>         at com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory.newConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:997)
>         at com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory.newConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:956)
>         at com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory.newConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:914)
>         at com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory.newConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:1068)
>
> ... ...
>
> Caused by: com.rabbitmq.client.ShutdownSignalException: connection
>   error   at
>   com.rabbitmq.utility.ValueOrException.getValue(ValueOrException.java:66)
>   at
>   com.rabbitmq.utility.BlockingValueOrException.uninterruptibleGetValue(BlockingValueOrException.java:36)
>   at
>   com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel$BlockingRpcContinuation.getReply(AMQChannel.java:494)
>   at
>   com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection.start(AMQConnection.java:315)
>   at
>   com.rabbitmq.client.impl.recovery.RecoveryAwareAMQConnectionFactory.newConnection(RecoveryAwareAMQConnectionFactory.java:64)
>   at
>   com.rabbitmq.client.impl.recovery.AutorecoveringConnection.init(AutorecoveringConnection.java:134)

My code snippet is:

```
ConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new ConnectionFactory();
connectionFactory.setUsername("myUser");
connectionFactory.setUsername("myPass");
connectionFactory.setHost("rabbitmq.test.com"); //also tried with the IP
connectionFactory.setPort(customPort);
connectionFactory.setVirtualHost("/myVHost");
Connection connection = connectionFactory.newConnection();
```

I also tried the compact setup:

```
connectionFactory.setUri("amqp://myUser:myPass@rabbitmq.test.com:customPort/myVHost");
```

Now...the strange part is that if I log into GUI, I can access the queues for that vhost...

Any ideas on this situation please? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You seem to use the `setUsername()` function for setting the password.